# "ifstream" not reading the entire file

Tags: c++

I have a file say "file.dat" which has around 1300 rows and 2 columns of numeric data. I want to read the contents of the file using ifstream. When I am using an object of ifstream to read this file it is truncating first 400 rows and displaying the last 900 rows.

I have tried putting flag `ios_base::binary` in the constructor of the ifstream object but the issue still stays the same. I have checked the data file and it shows all of the 1300 rows. I do have another ifstream object which is reading data from another file but I declared it separately using a different ifstream object. The code is kinda long but this is what it is basically doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("chi2_rse.dat", ios_base::in | ios::binary);

    double b;
    double chi2;

    while(fin >> b >> chi2){
        cout << b << "    " << chi2 << endl;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why ifstream is skipping the first 400 rows and not reading the entire file.

Comment: What is the actual format of the file you attempt to read? Is it a text file? Is it a raw binary file? If it's a text file then you should not be using the `ios::binary` flag.

Comment: And have you tried examining the file in a hex-editor, to make sure that the file really contains what you think it contains? That there aren't any weird unprintable characters messing things up?

Comment: Lastly, if the file is indeed text, then can you please edit your question to show the beginning of the file, the first few lines of it? Otherwise it's going to be hard to properly help you without guessing.

Comment: This code cannot possibly do what you are claiming.

Comment: @SomeprogrammerdudeYes I did put the same `ios::binary` flag while writing the file. I haven't tried the file in a hex-editor but that is a good idea. The reason I didn't put the whole code because it is long and is written in a Data Analysis framework by CERN called ROOT.

Comment: It could be that the console doesn't show more than 900 rows. Redirect the output to a file and check that

Comment: How do you *write* the data? Also using the ***text file*** `<<` operators? Don't use `<<` or `>>` on binary files, they will seldom do what you expect them to do.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values instead of using the default constructor and immediately modifying the object. That is, change `ifstream fin; fin.open("chi2_rse.dat", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);` to `ifstream fin("chi2_rse.dat", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);`.

Comment: @bolov That was indeed the case, the console is not showing up the whole contents of the file when I output it using `cout`. When I redirect the output to a file, it is showing me all the rows. Thanks for the suggestion. But I don't understand why this is happening though.

Comment: @lakshya91 it's ar archaic limitation of some consoles. They have a limited buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some consoles have a limited internal buffer so when the buffer is filled old data (output, input commands) are deleted to make room for the new output to show. When this happens a common symptom is that you can't scroll up a certain point (and you don't see earlier input commands)

You can check if the program output is ok by redirecting it to a file and then checking that file.

Answer (score 0):

For binary files, you should not use `>>` because it skips spaces and may modify the line endings.

I suggest using `read()`. You can define a vector which contains the data you need.

```
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size());
```